# How will I find the image of this function?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I'm given a function $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R, \space f(x) = |x|$ and told to find the image of it.

This was my attempt:

Claim: $f(\mathbb R) = \{|x|: x \in \mathbb R\} = B$

Proof:

($\subseteq$)

Suppose  $y \in f(\mathbb R)$. Therfore, $y = |x|$ where $x \in \mathbb R$. Therfore, $y \in B$.

Therefore $f(\mathbb R) \subseteq B$

($\supseteq$)

Suppose $y \in B$. Therfore, $y = |x|$ where $x \in \mathbb R$. But now, $f(x) = |x| = y$. Therfore, $y \in f(\mathbb R)$, which means that $B \subseteq f(\mathbb R)$.

Therefore, $f(\mathbb R) = B$

Is that proof correct? What can I improve on? It seems kind of redundant, but My prof did a similar example in class, and I'm sort of following the logic of his example to prove this question.

Comment: Actually it does not prove anything. The only thing you did was giving the image some name: $B$.

Comment: Maybe your claim must be $f(\mathbb R)=[0,+\infty)$